# weird problem with load () or live () !

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, load, live

I load a page with load () and then I create  dinamically a

tag. Then I use live() to bind a click event and fires a function. At the end a call unload ().

The problem is that when I load the same page again ( without refresh ) when on click the function will be fired twice. If I exit again (again with unload ()) and load the page again on click will fire 3 times and so on .... A sample of my code is:

```
$('#tab').click(function() {
 $('#formWrap').load('newPage.php');
});
$('div').after('<p class="ctr" ></p>');
$('p.ctr').live('click', function(e) {
   if($(e.target).is('[k=lf]')) { console.log ('one'); delete ($this); }
   else if ....
});
function delete () {
  $.post( 'update.php',  data);
}
```

I have other `$.post` inside on this page and also on the above live fnc and all work well. The above one  also works but like I said on the second load will fire twice and the 3 times and so on ...
The weird part for me is that if replece the console with console.log ('two'); save the page and load the page without refresh it will fire on a different rows - one two -

if I unload the page replace the console with console.log ('three'); and load again will fire one two and three.
I try to use:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'updateDB.php', data: data, type: 'POST', cache:false });

$.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false });

header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
```

none of this it's working. And I have this problem only on this fnc.
What do you think, it could be the reason, it remembers it remembers the previous action and it fires again?

Comment: you don't need to use live again, live supposed to be used only once and this handler will live forever , even for newly created elements.
Use bind instead or tweak your page lifecycle

Comment: The live fn it's inside the page that I load. When I call unload () It shouldn't unbind live

Comment: And like I said I have other $.post on the page and even inside live() but only one of this has this problem

Comment: the div where I loaded the page, it's removed, after I call unload()

Comment: that's the concept of live, compare with bind. Unless you explicitly remove live handler it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact the answer belongs to @vittore.

I'll just try to explain a little better what was happening:

the `live ()` fn was inside the page that I was loading. And on the first `load ()` the live fn assigns the handler to click. BUT when you use unload and then remove all the elements from that page the connection  between click and handlers remains.

And when I was loading again the same page (without refresh), the `live` function will keep the old handler and also attach the handler again, and so on every time `load ()` it is used.

the trick it's to use `die ()` before `unload ()`. BUT one more thing to take in account: we can't use chaining with `live()` (`$('div').children().live()` will not work ) AND ALSO although:

`$('.div .ctr').live()` will work.

just calling `$('.ctr').die()` will not work.

So you have to use for both fn the same selector `$('.ctr').live()` and then `$('.ctr').die()`

maybe this will help someone. AND also check the new 1.4.2 `delegate ()` and `undelegate ()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a typo by having ($this) vs $(this);
Also note that there is a delete operator in javascript so you might want to try another function name.
You might also be suffering from a cache somewhere (web servers by default set a cache for .js files)

Comment: $this is a variable in fact in original code is var $th = S(this).parent(). And delete () indeed I choose it wrong for this example but in the original script the function name is deleteCtr ();

Comment: probably it is a problem with live (). I try to unbind, like viitore suggested , and I used die () just before I called unload (). But I don't undestand why it doesn't resolve the problem